# Jekyll HTTP css not loading on HTTPS site

Tags: html, https, jekyll

My Jekyll built blog is at https://wys35.github.io/

Local site is OK, as the website is hosted as http, but once the site is commited (through Travis CI), when I visit wys35.github.io, I was redirected to https version of the website and the CSS (of a http link) is blocked as it is mixed content.

How can I rectify this problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look at the DevTools console:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://wys35.github.io/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://wys35.github.io/css/main.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

This site is served through HTTPS, therefore all of its content must be served through HTTPS.

When linking a resource to your document, you don't need to explicitly set `http:` or `https:`, only double slashes `//` will work fine, it will base on the current protocol of the page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//wys35.github.io/css/main.css">
```

Try setting `url` in `_config.yml` to `"//wys35.github.io"`

Comment: Thank you! This fixed all my CSS redirecting from HTTPS to HTTP and then subsequently not loading on github pages

Comment: It didn't work for me :/.  It's extra weird for me since if I "view source" on my page, all the links look like they are using https, but the developer console claims the page is trying to load resources over http

Comment: It didn't work for me :/.  It's extra weird for me since if I "view source" on my page, all the links look like they are using https, but the developer console claims the page is trying to load resources over http

Comment: @ZainRizvi I guess you visited the site via `http` not `https`.

Comment: adding double slashes to the url on _config.yml fixed my problem as well.